# How to include comma when converting Excel to CSV and while reading CSV to datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to convert Excel to CSV by Extracting Excel data to Datatable and then importing it into CSV. But I am replacing comma by space/empty character while constructing CSV. How to include comma if Excel Data field contains comma?
I don't want to replace it by any other character/include double quotes to the field.

here is my code:

```
        command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", connection)

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        writer = New StreamWriter(targetFile)

        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command)

        Dim dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable()

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)

        Dim columnString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim column As Integer

        For column = 0 To dataTable.Columns.Count - 1

            If column = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1 Then

                columnString.Append(dataTable.Columns(column).ToString())

            Else

                columnString.Append(dataTable.Columns(column).ToString() + ",")

            End If

        Next

        writer.WriteLine(columnString)

        Dim row As Integer
        Dim rowString As StringBuilder

        For row = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1


            rowString = New StringBuilder()

            For column = 0 To dataTable.Columns.Count - 1

                If column = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1 Then

                    rowString.Append(dataTable.Rows(row)(column).ToString().Replace(",", ""))


                Else

                    rowString.Append(dataTable.Rows(row)(column).ToString().Replace(",", "") + ",")

                End If

            Next

            writer.WriteLine(rowString)
        Next
```

Also How to read data from CSV to Datatable if I require to split csv line by comma into datatable.

Here is my code:

```
 Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sourceFileFullName)

        While Not sr.EndOfStream

            Dim line = sr.ReadLine()

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then

                If Not RowCount = 0 Then
                    chunkRowCount = chunkRowCount + 1
                    '//var chunkDataTable = ; //Code for filling datatable or whatever  
                    dt1.Rows.Add()

                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    Dim Cell As String
                    For Each Cell In line.Split(",")

                        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Cell)) Then

                            dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = DBNull.Value
                            i = i + 1

                        ElseIf Cell = "00.00.0000" Then

                            dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = DBNull.Value
                            i = i + 1

                        Else

                            dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = Cell
                            i = i + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                RowCount = RowCount + 1

                If chunkRowCount = 100000 Then

                    chunkRowCount = 0
                    Yield dt1
                    dt1.Clear()
                End If
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Would you not rather 'save as csv' from within Excel, and then take it from there?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, I have to do it programmatically. Also how to read csv to Datatable if it contains comma?

Comment: why not just write straight into csv. why do you need to store it in a datatable ?

Comment: With the constraints given,  the CSV will appear to have more columns than the source XLS when they go to read it

Comment: You are not using the CSV format when writing to the file - you are just writing a comma delimited string. Search for `VB.Net write CSV`. Also there are .Net tools for parsing CSV into columns. Not sure why you round trip to the file and just not deal with it in memory - separated in time?